# Android Webview shows error in emulator

Tags: android

i have a problem with loading a webview from a string url.
here is the code of an activity with only WebView.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String url=intent.getStringExtra("url");
    //EditText edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    //String url=edit.getText().toString();
    WebView webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.loadUrl(url);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}`
```

and code of the calling activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
public void onGo(View v)
{
    EditText edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,WebActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("url", edit.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

i have even added the android.permissions.INTERNET in the manifest
but still i cannot view the page with the click of the button in MainActivity.

Comment: can you specify the error?

Comment: the error says "the page cannot be displayed"

Comment: can you open the same page from a browser in a real device

Comment: yes the real device has the same error with "www.google.com" but not in another browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment

```
yes the real device has the same error with "www.google.com"
```

Use

```
http://www.google.com
```

Also make sure you have internet permission mentioned in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will extending `WebViewClient` this way make the code work for both `http://www.google.com` and `www.google.com` URLs?

Comment: Give a bit more detail on this answer